# How to deal with unstable API of a globally used framework

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, versioning, project-organization

**The situation:**

Our chief architect created a C++ library that is intended as a "runtime" for our domain of work (they are really several libs - think sdl, sdl_net, sdl_ttf, however with an C++ interface, and they always should be used altogether, even if you might need only one of them).

That is, these libraries are linked to a bunch of CRUD applications, other (more specific) libraries (think of a sprite library based on sdl), and larger scale applications (client/server, remote GUI).

**The issue:**

Due to a bunch of reasons (of course, lack of time, being one of them) the "runtime" library is still subject to change. New classes might be introduced, an existing class might be pulled into a class hierachy, method parameters might change and so on. Since there is no ABI, code linking the runtime will break and production software will crash when dynamically linked without proper versioning.

**Declined solutions:**

- Changes for the runtime library should introduce a new version. Binaries linking against `myrt.so.1` will still work when `myrt.so.2` is shipped, since `myrt.so.1` is not intended to be removed (for some time).

Reson for rejection: There will be a lot of new library versions "polluting"  the production environment. Worst case being each binary has its own `myrt` version.

- Static linking.

Reason for rejection: Together with the obvious bloat, the last statement from above virtually applies here as well.

- Keep maybe two `myrt` versions and rebuild dependencies that would otherwise break when shipping a new instalment of `myrt`.

Reason for rejection: There is no time to test the functionality of all dependencies (there is only little automatic testing) and the risk to ship untested binaries is deemed too high.

---

**Question**:

What else we could do? Do you see any way to revive one of the proposed solutions by tackling the rejection statements?

It's probably doctoring the symptoms rather than the cause (lack of automatic testing, lack of resources to actually create a stable API, etc.). Honestly, I don't see a way out of the bigger issues, although steps toward better testing are made.

Comment: Option #0: fire the chief architect?

Comment: How about versioning the pieces instead of versioning the entire library?  For example, if the hierarchy needs to be changed, make a new class instead of changing the old one.

Comment: @VaughnCato: Good point. Sadly, however, I hinted at it in a subclause - to be more clear: Versioning the pieces and only ship one according piece has been rejected as well ("those libraries form a unit, but the shared objects/DLLs are separated for sake of clarity/file organization").

Comment: If static linking is not an option, then any part of the API that is modified will potentially break something.  So the only real option is not to modify the API.  However, if you extend the API it should still be ok.  For example, don't add new members to existing classes, create new classes that derive from the old ones.  Don't replace the class methods, add new ones, etc.

Comment: @VaughnCato So I will suggest to change the framework while maintaining binary-compatibility (e.g. do not touch headers, avoid changing structure in a way that would break bc). Maybe refactor based upon those "hacks" every release cycle when extensive tests are performed anyway. To be updated when response is received.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that there is little willingness to deviate from the versioning of a whole "stack" of sublibs of `myrt.so.n`. I believe, the whole concept needs rethinking, but it will be difficult to pass this to the CA. That said, I will leave this question as is. While personally doubting it, maybe some killer idea will pop up.

Answer (score 1):

**4th solution**

Change the ABI of your library in the backward-compatible way. But it's not easy. The complexity depends on the initial architecture of the classes (usage of d-pointers and so on). Probably you'll need to introduce a huge break once to change the architecture of classes to make possible safe ABI additions in future.

Useful articles in this area:

- https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++
- https://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Examples
- http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/#Articles

Useful tools for automated analysis of ABI compatibility:

- [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/)
- [abi-dumper](https://github.com/lvc/abi-dumper)